# In React native How to pass session Id throughout all components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In React native I make ajax call and get the sessionid and setState that session id, How to pass that session id to all components throughout all components in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use redux to store data that need still in your whole app.

> https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053

Comment: I mean can I set the cookie and can I call that cookie where should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this will meet your requirement or not....
You can use global variables. It will be accessible throughout your app.
for e.g., 
global.sessionID = 11221122345;

now you can use this variable "sessionID" anywhere. just use global.sessionID to get the value.

Again, since I have just started learning React-Native so I have no idea whether its a good practice to use the global variables or not.